# Issue with mysql command

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have a table called benificiaries with following columns

```
custid varchar
accno varchar primarykey
name varchar
```

I have one record in that table with values

```
101
12345
john
```

Now I need to insert a record for another custid but same accno

```
 var data={"custid":"102","accno":"12345","name":"john"};
con.query('insert into benificiaries set ?',data)
```

But it is not allowing since accno is primary key..So how can i insert this?I can have same accountno once for different custid..Any ideas?

Comment: If there can be multiple entries with the same accno, then accno isn't a primary key. Make a [compound primary key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) from accno and custid, and you should be set.

Comment: @ConCave Then what will be query to create that table?I have no idea about this

Answer (score 1):

Check out your MySQL code here:

```
CREATE TABLE beneficiaries (
custid INT PRIMARY KEY,
accno INT,
name varchar(30)
);
```

Set custid as primary keys and observe the datatypes I've used for each column.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, you have make accno  and custid  as composite key

Comment: Then how the table needs to be created in this case?

Comment: see post from ConCave, it has the sample table

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't do this, because you've defined accno as primary key.
Primary key is exactly that - the primary key of the record. It is a unique value that positively identifies that record and only that record. If you can't guarantee that data to be unique per record, it cannot be your primary key.

This table seems like a mapping table, to me. Is it?
If so, it really doesn't need a primary key. If you absolutely MUST give it a primary key, for some reason, then just give the table a surrogate key using an autoincrementing integer column and make that the primary key for this table.

How is this table being used?
I'd say screw a primary key and just index on both accno and custid columns (if you do lookups by each).

If the combination of accno and custid is unique (probably is, given what this table seems to be), then you can define your primary key as a combination of accno and custid.

If, for some reason, you need to be able to have more than one record with the same values for both of those fields, then you have no natural key in this table anyway.

Comment: I cant have same accountno for one custid..For ex if there is custid 1 and accno 12345...Then I cant have the same accno for custid 1 but another custid can have accno 12345...So what query can we use create table  in this case

Comment: any idea on how the table needs to be created in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Because there can be multiple entries with the same accno, accno isn't a primary key. Make a compound primary key from accno and custid, and you should be set.

```
CREATE TABLE beneficiaries (
    custid INT,
    accno INT,
    name varchar
    PRIMARY KEY (custid, accno)
)
```

Comment: accno must be removed from Primary Key constraint and please provide a varchar() parameter and a semicolon at the end of your code.